# VS Code shows output in output but i want it in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want my output in terminal instead of output tab because output tab doesn't show correct output but when I right click and select "Run in terminal" it shows the correct output.

Comment: Which VS Code extensions did you use? Do you use the extension "Code Runner"?

Comment: How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, the Python extension provides the function of running python. Therefore, we can use the Python extension to output the result in the terminal: (The execution command of the green button in the upper right corner of VS Code is: `Run Python File in Terminal`)

[image]

Please try to "disable" the VS Code extension such as "Code Runner". The terminal it provides is an output terminal, so the result is displayed in "OUTPUT".